# How do I access a variable that I populate within a using block outside of that block?

Tags: c#, dispose, using-statement

I have an Xmlreader that I would like to load into an XMLDocument inside a 'using':
However, the problem is that the XMLDocument gets disposed once finished (after xml.Load(reader)).
I have tried including an int variable inside the 'using' and it also gets disposed.
However, in the first 'using' where I create the 'result' string, it does not get disposed after leaving the statement.
Why is that happening?

```
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URL_GET.ToString()) as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }            
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result)))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("ops:output");
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(reader);
        }
```

Comment: `int` variable gets disposed? Interesting...

Comment: There's no int variable in your code sample.  I'm with @SergeyBerezovskiy - I'd like to see an example of this :)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean - I would expect the *reader* to be disposed, but not the XmlDocument. It's notable that you're not actually *using* the XML document. What symptom are you seeing that leads you to believe the document is being disposed? (XmlDocument doesn't even implement IDisposable as far as I can tell...)

Comment: your string result does not get "disposed" because you declared and initialized it outside the using statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`xml` doesn't get disposed; it simply goes out of scope, so the *variable* is not accessible any more - however, nothing has happened to the object it referred to. Simply declare `xml` outside of the `using` scope:

```
XmlDocument xml;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("ops:output");
    xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(reader);
}
// Now, xml exists here
```

Comment: Dam you answering just before me :P removed my answer.

Comment: @TimBJames: Actually, you beat me by seven seconds - the only reason I didn't delete my own answer is that I supplied a little more explanation than you did... I guess you got the "Disciplined" badge, though ;-)

Comment: @user3472931: You should read up on the syntax and semantics regarding scopes and `using` statements, which are two different concepts.